# How to get date more than 14 days base on date in column?

Tags: mysql

Example: Claim Date = 14/3/2017 And today was 29/3/2017 it was more than 14 days.
I've tried DATEDIFF in Mysql it keep showing error somehow.

```
Example Table:
Table Name: 
**ec_claims**
ec_claims_id Primaryint(11)
ec_claims_date  date
```

CODE:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) AS DAYGAP FROM ec_claims
WHERE DAYGAP >= 14
```

Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'DAYGAP' in 'where clause'
```

Thank You For Reading This.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Did you mean [`datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)?

Comment: @GurV yea datediff, was typo edited.

Comment: @Wikunia updated my error message

Comment: You can't use DAYGAP >= 14 in 'where' clause because DATEDIFF is a summary function, although you can use summary functions in 'having' clause. In your case you just need to use DATE_ADD instead of DATEDIFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATE_ADD` function like

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -14 DAY) AS fourteenDayAgo
```

In your case

```
SELECT ec_claims_date FROM ec_claims
WHERE DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -14 DAY)> ec_claims_date
```

or like you write, you must repeat it in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) AS DAYGAP FROM ec_claims
  WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) >= 14
```

Comment: Thank You very much! The 3rd query is what i looking for! & Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause does not allow the use of aliases.

You can either use your entire expression without the alias in the where clause, like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) AS DAYGAP FROM ec_claims
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) >= 14
```

or alternatively, you can use `HAVING` in place of `WHERE` and go ahead with the alias.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),ec_claims_date) AS DAYGAP FROM ec_claims
HAVING DAYGAP >= 14
```